# Tables not getting auto-created in Apache Derby when using EJB3/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb-3.0, derby

I have an EJB3 entity bean Player which is annotated as given below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAYER")
public class Player {
    public Player() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I am using Apache Derby DB to persist this. I have a **persistence.xml** file which explains the hibernate properties and I have define `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="PlayerApp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.cricinfo.domain.Player</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>  
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
            value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PlayerAppDB;create=true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />           
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

But when I try to persist this object I get an exception saying

```
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Table/View 'PLAYER' does not exist.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
```

Isn't it supposed to auto create the tables since I have set the property **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** ? Or is there something that I am missing?

My main method is as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Player p = new Player();
    p.setFirstName("A");
    p.setLastName("BC");

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PlayerApp");
    EntityManager entityMgr =  factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = entityMgr.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    entityMgr.persist(p);
    tx.commit();
    entityMgr.close();
    factory.close();
}
```

Comment: try setting it to `update`, just to test

Comment: 1. check the logs for any errors during startups (hbm2ddl reports them in 1 line, so look carefully) 2. Try with a different database

Comment: I am not getting anything on the logs now. I will try your 2nd suggestion on Postgres and let you know

Comment: Worked like charm in PostGres

Comment: too bad.. try the latest version of derby, or report a bug in hibernate.

Comment: Some more info on this: I had to change the id to an int variable since PostGres threw an exception saying Strings are not acceptable in Sequence.  I tried this again with Derby DB after making the id as int. Now it worked. Postgres also didn't allow me to insert a String id, but it threw a proper exception message. So can it be considered that Derby DB is not throwing proper exception message for the error?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below property

```
<property name="hibernate.generateDdl" value="true" />
```