# Apache Derby [Hibernate framework] dosn't see created table. [Java EE + JSP]

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, jdbc, derby

i'm trying to solve a problem but jdbc keeps me distant.

I have created table USERS and want to insert some data with Hibernate but i'm unable to.
I can't understand why, because i had the same db configuration on previous easier example and it worked correctly.
Here's part of code from my bean :

```
    public void newUser() throws ParseException{
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tran = session.beginTransaction();

    java.sql.Date dt = new java.sql.Date(year-1900,month,day);

    entity.Users user = new entity.Users();
    user.setBirthdate(dt);
    user.setFirstname(inputName);
    user.setLastname(inputSurname);
    user.setEmail(inputEmail);
    user.setPassword(inputPassword);
    user.setGender(selectedGender);

    Rights t = new Rights(3,"user");

    user.setPrivilageType(t);

    session.save(user);
    tran.commit();
}
```

And stack trace:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [entity.Users]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [entity.Users]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at beans.RegistrationBean.newUser(RegistrationBean.java:155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'USERS' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:30)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Table/View 'USERS' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
    ... 63 more
```

I'd love any help.

Comment: This related question has some things to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579180/tables-not-getting-auto-created-in-apache-derby-when-using-ejb3-hibernate?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately nothing changes when i try to use solutions from the case You have given. Just in addition i have configurated hibernate files properly. They work on aby other Project i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have solved the problem. It was quite simple. I just had to rename tables name from lower case to upper case.